# javascript - Why DOM wrapper methods use the first element and the whole element list inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, dom, language-design, libraries

Libraries I've seen have DOM wrappers that inclusively handle only the first element of the list in some case, like:

```
return this[0].innerHTML
```

and use the whole list in some other like:

```
for( var i=0, l=this.length; ++i<l; ) this[i].className = cls;
return this
```

Why is this approach accepted?

I think singling out the first element defeats the purpose of having methods that apply the same thing on the rest of the list. Isn't it bad to have dubious functions? I know it suits many people..but it feels inconsistent and I'm interested in why this is accepted so widely.

EDIT as an example:

[jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the
>   first match will have its HTML content returned.

why not all?

the [hide()](https://github.com/ded/bonzo/blob/master/bonzo.js#L628) method in bonzo, from Dustin Diaz

```
//...
hide: function () {
  return this.each(function (el) {
     el.style.display = 'none'
  })
}
```

why not only the first?

Comment: Which DOM wrapper methods in particular are you talking about?  There are a lot of libraries out there, each with its own architecture.

Comment: If it's bad, then what would you expect to get in the first case? How would you include all elements of the set in that case?

Comment: @Pointy: it's in general. but I'll add some examples asap. 
Madbreaks: I know it's a soft spot for library lovers..but I intended it as an informal question. does this prove that there are people who don't like others who question their tools?

Comment: @pimvdb I'd except to have a wrapper for single elements and another for domlists, because it's confusing to have an ambiguous tool, but everyone seems to be ok with it. I'm interested in why. is there a valid logic in this implementation?

Comment: @tenshou: So you basically want `Wrapper.one("...").html()` to *get* and `Wrapper.multiple("...").html("foo")` to *set*? Personally I think the difference in arguments is enough - it's not difficult to get used to.

Comment: @pimvdb not just get/set, but to work on them in any way. something like how `.getElementById()` returns one element and `getElementsByTagName()` a `NodeList` but as if they'd share configuration methods that apply their respective content(single node, nodelist). I know it's not hard, only just strange..and I can see how javascript (due to it's dynamic typing) suits such approach, where the arguments are giveaways of the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessor methods in jQuery return single values because it's simpler and more generally useful. If the `.html()` API were to return the value if `innerHTML` for all elements, that'd mean it'd have to return an array. That, in turn, would mean that in the most common case of wanting the contents of a single element, you'd have to add the array access.  There's also the problem of knowing exactly which returned value goes with which selected element.  In other words, if `.html()` returned an array of element contents:

```
var contentList = $('.someClass, span, .hidden .container').html();
```

If "contentList" were just a simple array, what use would it be?  How would the code know for each element which DOM node it came from?  Of course there are solutions to this, but again the simple case is made complicated in order to support a rare general case.

It's possible of course to get the list yourself with `.map()`.  I think this is just an issue of smart, practical, pragmatic API design.

Comment: Don't get me started on `.triggerHandler()` however :-)

Comment: It's actually odd that `.text()` takes all elements into account, whereas `.html()` does not.

Comment: I see, so the point of the decision behind these APIs is that there are common use cases. I can't argue with this even more so that you mentioned .map() . Though I meant something along the lines of the querySelector API. it has `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` and their return is hinted even in the method name. but if you do `$(".someclass").hide()` you need to know it will hide everything, and if you just want to hide the first you need to go around it in some way. I know it is nitpicking and I feel awful for it but I'm interested! and you raise a good point here so I'll accept.

Comment: @tenshou: If that's jQuery, then (just so you know) `.eq(0)` will only take the first element.

Comment: @pimvdb yes that was an odd decision in my opinion (the decision to have `.text()` not mirror `.html()`)